# Enabling Session Directory under Terminal Server Configuration Tool and Server Settings

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server

I'm trying to add a Terminal Server Session Directory client to an already fully functional Session Directory cluster which today runs two clients as well as the server.

I've been reading up on both Google, Microsoft KB's as well as old documentation from an earlier employee but to no avail.

The step I'm stuck at is when I open up Terminal Server Configuration Tool (`tscc.msc`), and choose Server Settings. I know there should be an option saying "Session Directory" on the right hand side along with Active Desktop, Licensing and whatnot, but it's not there.

I've logged on to both the other already functional clients and checked the same list and there the Session Directory option sure is both visible as well as working good with the specified information.

This picture is the same view that I'm looking at at the moment, but mine is missing the bottom option that says "Session Directory."

[image: TSCC view]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

I'm using Windows Standard Edition and NOT Enterprise, that's an easy way to throw away four workdays. *sigh*

[Let's hope this works](http://www.ehow.com/how_6553165_change-server-2003-standard-enterprise.html).

Answer (score 1):

*Thank you for your answer, but I'm not in administration mode.
It says "Per user" right now and gives me directions on how to enable administration mode.*

... You can ignore that reply, I'm using Windows Standard Edition and NOT Enterprise, that's an easy way to throw away four workdays, sigh

Lets hope this works: http://www.ehow.com/how_6553165_change-server-2003-standard-enterprise.html

Comment: If you want to reply to someone you should use the 'add comment' link, on their answer so the notification system works.  Not having the enterprise version of 2003 would also cause this.  A 2003 std -> 2003 ent in-place install has worked for me in the past, but a clean install tends to better.  I do think you should also consider automating (gpo/scripts) as much of your terminal server setup is possible.  That way you can repeat the installs exactly the same way every time.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll do better next time. And thank you loads for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Just a question, but are you certain you have enabled 'Application Server Mode'?

If your screen likes this your are in administration mode, not application server mode.

[image: TS Admin Mode]